# How to get the iOS Device Model Number (eg. "MD235CH/A")?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to find an iOS API to get the device's model number string (e.g., "MD235CH/A"), as displayed in Settings->General->About.

Does anyone know how to do this in Objective C and/or Swift?

Comment: Clarified the question--OP didn't specify whether Objective C or Swift, so included both.

Comment: Take a look at [UIDevice Extension](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension).